# Create a size legend in plotly and give it a title

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to know how could give a title to this plotly legend

```
library(plotly)
figB <- plot_ly(x = 1, y = seq(30, 5, by = -5), 
                size = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
                sizes = c(1, 30),
                type = "scatter",
                mode = "markers",
                color = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
                colors = c("#440154FF", "#1F968BFF", "#FDE725FF"), 
                marker = list(sizeref = 0.1, 
                              sizemode = "area"),
                height = 275, width = 100) %>%

  layout(
    xaxis = list(zeroline = F, showline = F, showticklabels = F, showgrid = F),
    yaxis = list(showgrid = F, side = "right")) %>% # numbers on right (as fig legend)
   hide_colorbar()
figB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a title to your "legend" using `annotations`:

```r
library(plotly)

library(plotly)
figB <- plot_ly(
  x = 1, y = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
  size = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
  sizes = c(1, 30),
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  color = seq(30, 5, by = -5),
  colors = c("#440154FF", "#1F968BFF", "#FDE725FF"),
  marker = list(
    sizeref = 0.1,
    sizemode = "area"
  ),
  height = 275, width = 100
) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(zeroline = F, showline = F, showticklabels = F, showgrid = F),
    yaxis = list(showgrid = F, side = "right"),
    annotations = list(
      x = 1,
      y = 35,
      text = "Size",
      xref = "x",
      yref = "y",
      showarrow = FALSE
    )
  ) %>%
  hide_colorbar()
#> Warning: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values.
figB
```

[image]